# PyQt program startup is very slow on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, pyqt

When I run the following example of PyQt code in Terminal:

```
#coding = utf8
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = QtGui.QWidget()
widget.resize(250, 150)
widget.setWindowTitle('simple')
widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I got the following messages:

```
Got bus address:  "unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-i0C7rhmhFB,guid=6b91faa5b449dbb3ca941d6e0000001d" 
Connected to accessibility bus at:  "unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-i0C7rhmhFB,guid=6b91faa5b449dbb3ca941d6e0000001d" 
Registered DEC:  true 
Error in contacting registry 
"org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply" 
"Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken." 
Could not query active accessibility event listeners. 
Registered event listener change listener:  true
```

The window shows after about 20 seconds. I think it should be very quickly to show an empty window. How to solve this problem?

Here is the version information:

- ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit
- Python 2.7.3rc2
- QT 4.8.0 & PyQT 4.9.1

Comment: I have the same issue. app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv) take more than 10 seconds... except in root mode with sudo when it is immediat !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my machine that code runs instantly - Kubuntu 11.10, KDE 4.8.2

I think the issue might be in your environment configuration, especially as you are running the unreleased version - Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: after updated to the release version 12.04, the problem gone.